# I'm inputing data in a db using mysqlcommand, but some variables are identified e other are not, check the code

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

My code:

```
Private Sub btnEnviartranche_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEnviartranche.Click
 
    Try
        connection.Close()
        connection.Dispose()
        connection.Open()
        Dim busca As New MySqlCommand("SELECT MAX(cod_tranche) +1 As id_last_tranche FROM long_short_tranche", connection)
        Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(busca)
        Dim table As New DataTable()
        adapter.Fill(table)
        Dim retorno = busca.ExecuteReader
        Dim id_ultima_tranche = ""
 
        Dim tipo_operacao As String = dg_ctrlv.Rows(1).Cells(0).Value.ToString
        Dim ativo As String = dg_ctrlv.Rows(2).Cells(2).Value.ToString
        Dim quantidade As String = dg_ctrlv.Rows(2).Cells(3).Value.ToString
        Dim preco_executado As String = dg_ctrlv.Rows(2).Cells(4).Value.ToString
 
        If retorno.Read() Then
            id_ultima_tranche = retorno.GetString(0)
        End If
        connection.Close()
        connection.Dispose()
        connection.Open()
 
        Dim nova_tranche = id_ultima_tranche + 1
        Dim hora = DateTime.Now
        ' ======= The error happens on the line below ========
        Dim query As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO long_short_tranche  (cod_tranche, cod_cliente, nocional, title_operation, tipo_operacao, ativo, quantidade, preco_executado, data_hora)  SELECT ('" & nova_tranche & "', cod_cliente, nocional, title_operation,'" & hora & "','" & tipo_operacao & "','" & ativo & "','" & quantidade & "','" & preco_executado & "')  FROM  long_short WHERE title_operation = '" & cbox_operacao.Text & "' AND confirmacao = 'Sim' AND flg_visualizar = 1  ", connection)
        Dim adapter2 As New MySqlDataAdapter(query)
        Dim table2 As New DataTable()
        adapter2.Fill(table2)
        Dim retorno2 = query.ExecuteReader
 
        MessageBox.Show("Dados atualizados com sucesso!")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Erro ao consultar tabela!")
    End Try
 
End Sub
```

This is what happens

[image: error]

Comment: The full code is here: https://pastebin.com/s52mhM4P

Answer (score 1):

This is crazy-vulnerable to sql injection. **NEVER** use string concatenation like that to put values into a query! It's very likely the problem is a stray apostrophe somewhere in the data, and proper SQL coding practice would have avoided this, while also fixing the MASSIVE security issue.

Try it like this:

```vb
Dim sql As String = "
INSERT INTO long_short_tranche 
    (cod_tranche, cod_cliente, nocional, title_operation, tipo_operacao, ativo, quantidade, preco_executado, data_hora) 
SELECT @nova_tranche, cod_cliente, nocional, title_operation, @hora, @tipo_operacao, @ativo, @quantidade, @preco_executado 
FROM long_short 
WHERE title_operation =  @operacao AND confirmacao = 'Sim' AND flg_visualizar = 1
"

Using connection As New MySqlConnection("connection string here")
Using query As New MySqlCommand(sql, connection)
    query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nova_tranche", nova_tranche)
    query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hora", hora)
    query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo_operacao", tipo_operacao)
    query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ativo", ativo)
    query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantidade", quantidade)
    query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@preco_executado", preco_executado)
    query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@operacao", cbox_operacao.Text)
    
    connection.Open()
    query.ExecuteNonQuery() ' ...


End Using
End Using
```

Comment: I get an 'object reference not set to an instance of object' error message

Comment: Not from this code, you won't, unless one of those variables is `null`.

Comment: From this code, yes. Full code can't be found here: https://pastebin.com/umrbNCrz

Comment: You know you have a password in that pastebin, right?

Comment: Also, nowhere in that pastebin do  you use this code. There's something similar beginning around line 80, but it's still doing the very bad string concatenation with the HUGE GAPING SECURITY ISSUE, and it's still not handling the connection object as it should (pro tip: trying to re-use your connection like this actually makes things _slower_, because it interferes with the existing connection pooling in ADO.Net). Especially, **you can't re-open a connection once you call `Dispose()`.**